# Remove Border of UISearchBar in iOS7

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I'm trying to remove border of UISearchBar in iOS 7. In iOS 6 it's working fine. I created the UISearchBar programatically. I tried almost every thing from Stack Overflow and Google.

SearchBar looking right now
[image: SearchBar looking right now]

What i want to achieve
[image: What i want to achieve]

I tried all these stuffs mentioned below

```
searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1;
searchBar.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
```

and

```
for (id img in searchBar.subviews)
{       
     if ([img isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")])
     {     
            [img removeFromSuperview];    
     }
}
```

and

```
for (UIView *sub in self.tableView.tableHeaderView.subviews) {
    if ([sub isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        sub.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

but still no success.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found the solution: set the `barTintColor` of `UISearchBar` to `clearColor`

```
topSearchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: but sometimes work for this solution , i am using identical code , but one works and the other show black color , so i use whitecolor to fix it . strange

Comment: In my case, it always showed black color when I set clear color :(

Comment: Try doing nerowolfe's answer:

Comment: @Thought-Beast May be you set the alpha to some minimum value line .1 or something?

Answer (score 109):

Set Search Style = minimal in Search Bar properties in IB

Or

```
Swift:
searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;

Swift 3:
searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal;
```

Comment: i created the `UISearchBar` programatically.

Comment: searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;

Comment: searchBarStyle of UISearchBar is available from iOS7.0 and later.

Comment: Thanks!!! work!!  Xamarin.iOS code

 searchBar.SearchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal;

Answer (score 60):

Setting searchBarStyle to UISearchBarStyleMinimal messed up my color setup, so doing this instead fixed the issue.

```
[self.searchField setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc]init]];
```

For those looking for this option in Swift 4:

```
searchField.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .any, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.default)
```

Comment: this is better than any other answer here!

Comment: This is the one that worked for me , and I tried almost all of the other ones here .. Xcode 11.3.1

Answer (score 29):

For Swift, these 2 lines are enough:

```
self.search.isTranslucent = false
self.search.backgroundImage = UIImage()
```

And then, apply required color that you want:

```
self.search.barTintColor = .red
```

Answer (score 11):

> **This only works if `.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine`;
>   .**

---

My experiments conclusion,

- If you're on iOS7 and above, and if you'll set, `searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];` then you'll not able to customise background colour of `UISearchBar`.
- if you'll set `searchBarStyle` to `UISearchBarStyleMinimal` then it'll mess the color of `UISearchBar` as said by @Rich Fox.

So, `[self.searchField setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc]init]];` solution to remove border.

Update with sample:

```
UISearchBar *search = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
search.tag = kTagSearchBar;
search.delegate = self;
search.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
search.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
search.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50);
search.placeholder = @"Search";
search.barTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
search.translucent = NO;
search.opaque = NO;
search.showsCancelButton = NO;
[search setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
[self.view addSubview:search];

//customize textfield inside UISearchBar
@try {
    for (id object in [[[search subviews] firstObject] subviews])
    {
        if (object && [object isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {
            UITextField *textFieldObject = (UITextField *)object;
            textFieldObject.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            textFieldObject.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
            textFieldObject.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
            textFieldObject.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
            break;
        }
    }
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Error while customizing UISearchBar");
}
@finally {

}
```

will give you:

[image]

Comment: This is correct. Setting the background image removed the border.

Answer (score 4):

Neither only `barTintColor`, `backgroundImage` nor `backgroundColor` alone were doing it for me, but doing them all together worked for me:

```
self.searchBar.translucent      = NO;
self.searchBar.barTintColor     = [styleManager currentSearchBarTintColor];
self.searchBar.backgroundImage  = [UIImage new];
self.searchBar.backgroundColor  = [styleManager currentSearchBarTintColor];
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay. There are so many answers, but they are too complex. 
I've found this solution:

**Swift 3 (4)**

```
searchBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .top, barMetrics: .default)
searchBar.backgroundColor = .primary
```

Where .primary is

```
extension UIColor {

    static var primary:UIColor {
        return "#5163F4".color
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
self.searchBar.translucent = NO;
self.searchBar.opaque = NO;
if ([self.searchBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setSearchBarStyle:)]) {
    self.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
}

// iOS 7 remove 1 px bottom border
if ([self.searchBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBarTintColor:)]) {
    self.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
self.searchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;

// to remove the 1px bottom border iOS 5, 6
[self.searchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor clearColor] andSize:CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f)]];
```

The order of code seems does matter. It doesn't work if I set the barStyle before the searchBarStyle.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 2.1 in Xcode 7.2, this worked for me.

```
self.searchController.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
```

My full code below.

```
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
self.searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit() 
tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 181/255, blue: 229/255, alpha: 1.0)
self.searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 181/255, blue: 229/255, alpha: 1.0)
self.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 181/255, blue: 229/255, alpha: 1.0)
self.searchController.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
definesPresentationContext = true
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)createNavigationBar
{
    _searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]init];
    _searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _searchBar.placeholder = @"Search";
    _searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    self.navigationItem.titleView = _searchBar;
    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"SearchBar":_searchBar};
    NSArray *constraint_POS_V = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[SearchBar(30)]|"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                          views:viewsDictionary];
    NSArray *constraint_POS_H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-15-[SearchBar]-15-|"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                          views:viewsDictionary];
    [_searchBar.superview addConstraints:constraint_POS_V];
    [_searchBar.superview addConstraints:constraint_POS_H];

}
```

[image]