# remove searchbar black border

Tags: ios, swift

I have a search bar that looks like this:
[image]

Is there anyway to remove that black border on the top?

I tried the `minimal` bar approach but got:
[image]

So the border was removed but now I would need to somehow color the inner field white.

I tried:

```
        if let searchTextField = searchBar.valueForKey("searchField") as? UITextField {
             searchTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    }
```

But it didn't seem to change anything.

I'm looking for a solution to either of these problems. I just want the pink border with the white text field.

**Edit:**

There is a similar question for iOS7 but the accepted answer did not work for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove Border of UISearchBar in iOS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899642/remove-border-of-uisearchbar-in-ios7)

Comment: @JAL i tried the accepted answer there with no luck. Might've changed in iOS8

Comment: Try iterating through the subviews like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26273321/2415822.  Remember, just because the answer has been accepted doesn't mean it works for everyone.  Look at all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an image filled with the pink color:

[image]

And setting it as the `backgroundImage` for the search bar did the trick.