# How to change border of Search bar (Swift)

Tags: swift, uisearchbar

i am trying to remove search bar border but not able to do , i have set search bar background color to clear still rounded border is come , i want [image: search bar like this]

but my search  bar looks like this [image: i was]how i create search bar like this

thank you

Comment: You can create custom search bar using UITextField.

Comment: yes , i want only bottom border if i use this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899642/remove-border-of-uisearchbar-in-ios7 it wont work

Comment: @Asmita what have you tried? give more details

Comment: Customizing search bar takes some work instead you can use UITextField and customize it. It is the easy way

Comment: Thanks Guys done with set searchbar.backgroundImage = UIImage() & added uiview in between searchbar & tableview , know its not correct way to do this but was not able to add only bottom border to searchbar

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution is to choose a color that matches the background (white in this case)

**Swift 4**

```
UISearchBar.appearance().barTintColor = .white
```